# Validity of Coronavirus Curves - Are we using the correct baseline?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, curves

For most analysis (models), are we inaccurately assuming that the newly reported cases are the number of actual new cases? Could this exponentially growing number just be a function of the way testing is being rolled out and not represent the actual growth rate of the virus? Should we be basing the growth rate off of hospitalizations instead?

I just have to ask myself if our testing capability is expanding exponentially and since we can see symptoms for up to 12 days in these people that we are not making the curve look exponential when it may not really be doing that?

For my example, if my state currently has 50K with covid19 and lets say it grows to 60K over the next week. If testing is rolled out with exponentially more tests each day, wouldn't that appear there are exponentially new cases but in reality it's grown on a flat linear line?

Should we use the hospitalization curve since that is the capacity we care about anyway?

Comment: My guess is the story goes something like this. The death rate and # of cases graphs are clearly exponential. Are there some built in correlations to the number of cases graphs? Probably. But I don't think anyone would seriously doubt that this pandemic is growing exponentially. Better to lean on the side of caution since there are tons of people who are unthinkably ignorant. Also, you are severely taking for granted the importance of not sending people to the hospital and flooding the medical community. Much better to lean on the side of caution.

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't agree that it's "wildly" off-topic (at worst "mildly" off-topic). Diseases modelling is a big area of applied mathematics, and correct mathematical modelling is very much a mathematical skill. It doesn't fit within the usual problem/exercise-based mould that we typically see here, but I do think we should accept such questions. The question could benefit from a lot more context though, such as details about the current model being questioned, as well as details about the mathematical background of the asker.

Comment: I agree with @user759562. I get that sometimes we do math and the application isn't obvious. We certainly shouldn't shy away when it is. And by we, I'm hoping for people a lot smarter than me.

Comment: @EricWofsey: What do you mean nothing to do with math? The entire question is about a lurking variable driving an exponential pattern. I've taught this kind of stuff to my stats students. Also, the question touches on Type I and Type II errors in an extremely real and profound way.